# What causes permission to be denied for mounting rootfs, home, messeage queue, kernel file system, during boot?

Tags: fedora, permissions, boot, troubleshooting

My Fedora 27 x64 fails to boot after hard reset. It shows:

```
Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System,
Failed to start Remount and Kernel File Systems,
Failed to mount Kernel Debug File System,
Failed to mount Huge Pages File System [3]
```

and lots of other failures comes after these.
See https://photos.app.goo.gl/qBUxT40zA2MTLTwO2

In all these cases

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/mount: Permission denied
```

is given as a reason.
How can it be? Doesn't it recognize it's own filesystems?

I have 3 kernels:

```
vmlinuz-4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.15.13-300.fc27.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.15.14-300.fc27.x86_64
```

no matter which one I try to boot the same happens.

So far I have:

1. Checked filesystem integrity with fsck. All partitions are clean.
2. Checked disk health reported by SMART and performed both - short and long tests. Disk is perfectly healthy.
3. Rebuilt initramfs. Mounted boot, proc, sys, dev in /mnt, chroot and sudo dracut.

Followed suggestions and:

4. Performed 
   `fsck -f on /dev/mapper/fedora-home`, got:

   `tree extents for i-node 524820 (on level 2) could be narrower. Fix?<y>Y`

Allowed to fix this.

And the same for /dev/mapper/fedora-root, /dev/sda1 (boot partition) confirmed they are clean. One more error of the same kind was found for an extra partition for data files.

5. `rpm -V --all | grep -v " [cg] "` returned as follows:

```
.M.......    /run/libgpod
..5....T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/commit_num
.......T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/file_contexts
.......T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/homedir_template
S.5....T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern
.M.....T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/seusers
.M.....T.    /var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/users_extra
.M.......    /var/run/pluto
not exists   /var/run/abrt
.M.......    /var/log/audit
not exists   /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/85-display-manager.preset
S.5....T.    /usr/share/icons/Crux/icon-theme.cache
S.5....T.    /usr/share/icons/Mist/icon-theme.cache
```

6. ```
   rpm -V "$(rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/mount)"
   .M....G..  g /var/log/lastlog
   ```
7. `fixfiles check /usr`

   ```
   libsemanage.semanage_make_sandbox: Error removing old sandbox directory /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp. (Read only file system). 
   genhomedircon: Could not begin transaction: Read only file system
   ```

Among many lines similar to to the one below:

```
Would relabel /usr/src/handbrake/trunk/build/contrib/lib from unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
```

a few interesting ones are:

```
Would relabel /usr/sbin/mount.nilfs2 from unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:mount_exec_t:s0
Would relabel /usr/sbin/umount.nilfs2 from unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:mount_exec_t:s0
Would relabel /usr/sbin/mkfs.nilfs2 from unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:fsadm_exec_t:s0
```

8. Proved RAM works fine - memtest86 didn't find any errors during 3.5
   passes and over 8h test time.

   **9. Disabled SELinux (SELinux=disabled in /etc/selinux/config) and restarted. System started without any error!** This proves problem is in SELinux policies. I believe I should start with checking those 6 top SELinux policies that have been changed somehow (see p. 5). The question is how to do it wisely.
9. Checked local modifications to SELinux config files and file_contexts:

   ```
   semanage module -C -l
   Module name              Priority  Language
   semanage fcontext -C -l
   fcontext SELinux                                 type               Context
   /usr/bin/mount                                     all files          system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0
   /usr/share/dnfdaemon/dnfdaemon-system              all files          system_u:object_r:rpm_exec_t:s0
   /var/run/media/przemek/extra(/.*)?                 all files          system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo                                all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo/_cache                         all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo/config                         all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo/content                        all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo/content/folders.json           all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   /var/www/html/photo/iv-config/language             all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
   ```

Interestingly fcontext of the /usr/bin/mount has changed.

The system runs 24h/day as a simple home server (www, mail, etc.).
From time to time (say once a few weeks) it freezes completely. HDD keeps writing something (repetitive, although irregular sound). No reaction to keyboard, mouse, remote SSH access. Many times I have tried to leave it overnight, but it does not recover, so I am forced to hard reset it each time this happens. This time I haven't waited, but hard reset it after just a few minutes. Unfortunately since then it cannot boot.

I remembered that a minute or less before the system froze Firefox message box appeared telling me that some script became irresponsive. I don't remember my choice (kill it/wait).

Hardware: Gigabyte GB-BACE-3160 Brix PC with Hitachi HTS725032A9A364 2.5" HDD and 4GB LPDDR3 RAM (default clock).

More details [[here]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5849455#post5849455)

[image: Failed to mount messages during boot]
[image: Permission denied to mount POSIX Message File System, Kernel Debug File System]
[image: Permission denied to mount Huge Pages File System, Remount Root and Kernel File Systems]

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1054286-start-0.html It could be a permissions/file ownership issue. It could also be bad RAM, have you tested RAM ? Another good read is https://linux-audit.com/auditing-systemd-solving-failed-units-with-systemctl/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I haven't tested RAM yet. As to the ownership I will try to check it.

Comment: ah, of course.  Since system-remount-fs failed, your root filesystem is still mounted read-only. Since you are able to run mount manually, you can just `mount / -oremount,rw`.

Comment: Once you have a read-write FS, you can run e.g. `fixfiles -v restore /what/you/want`. `-v` is optional, I just like to see what it's doing as it does it. I don't know what you want to do with that handbreak source code, I guess you can just fixfiles the whole of `/usr` though and if you have to sort your source code out later, it probably won't be too hard.

Comment: I've remounted in rw and fixfiles -v restore for mount, umount and mkfs. It didn't help.

Comment: @thecarpy Thanks for the link. Suppose some files have incorrect permissions or ownership. How could I find these files? For example could I run some command to list all executable files from /bin /sbin not owned by root?

Comment: Since rpm -V (p. 5 above) didn't return any "U" or "G" flags set no files have changed user or group. Furthermore I couldn't find any files in /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, which were meant to be executable for root, but weren't.

Comment: RAM is ok - checked with memtest (see p. 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was caused by improper file context of the `/usr/bin/mount` file: `samba_share_t`.**

The file context change wasn't caused by some error due to hard reset, but... by my imprudent decision to follow the first suggestion of SELinux Alert Browser. See the screenshot below.
[image]

This first suggestion was to change `/usr/bin/mount` file context to `samba_share_t` to allow smbd to access getattr.

**The solution was:**

1. to delete invalid file context, restore default and relabel the file:

   ```
   [root@atlas ~]# ls -Z /usr/bin/mount
   system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 /usr/bin/mount
   [root@atlas ~]# semanage fcontext -d /usr/bin/mount
   [root@atlas ~]# restorecon -v /usr/bin/mount
   Relabeled /usr/bin/mount from system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 to system_u:object_r:mount_exec_t:s0
   [root@atlas ~]# ls -Z /usr/bin/mount
   system_u:object_r:mount_exec_t:s0 /usr/bin/mount
   ```
2. reboot system.

It could be done in emergency console, but I have used the console to put SELinux into permissive mode, boot system and then change the file context as described above.

When I have checked modified SELinux contexts of files (see p. 10 of my initial post) I have noticed that context of the mount looked suspicious. At the moment I realized that shortly before the problem started I have imprudently followed the first suggestion of SELinux Alert Browser to change mount file context. 
The same suggestion appeared now, after system repair and restart, so I was able to attach the screenshot below.

Credit for @sourcejedi for pointing SELinux may be causing the problem and for his kind help!

Answer (score 3):

> What causes permission to be denied for mounting rootfs, home, messeage queue, kernel file system, during boot?
>
> [...]
>
> In all these cases
>
> ```
> Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/mount: Permission denied
> ```
>
> is given as a reason. How can it be? Doesn't it recognize it's own filesystems?

The reason that it can't mount any of these filesystems, is literally that it cannot run the `mount` program due to a permission denied error.  That's what the log messages you found are saying.  We anticipate you will see the same error if you try to run `mount` yourself...

It sounds very much like the system on disk has been corrupted.

**Generally, systems which freeze will not be happy, and this is not an entirely unexpected outcome. It is likely you are having a problem with your hardware, a kernel bug, or a hardware bug which the kernel currently does not know how to work around.**

Faulty RAM can cause weird things, and it's relatively cheap to replace, so it's definitely worth looking at.  You can use e.g. `memtest86+` to test the RAM.  Thanks to @thecarpy for suggesting this.

**If Linux has a problem dealing some new but otherwise popular hardware, someone else might get the problem fixed in a newer version of Linux. If the hardware has been around for a while, or other Linux users don't use it, it might be very hard to fix.**

I used one such system myself, affected by an issue like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail) - which seems to have been an issue with very low power-draw Intel CPUs[[1]](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051#c752)[[2]](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051#c860) - I think the J-series like your Celeron J3160 is somewhat higher power, so I'm not sure whether or not it could be the same issue.

---

However, if we ignore that entirely and wonder how to look at what the immediate cause of an "impossible" message like this might be, I have two more techniques to suggest.  (And then a nitpick one of the techniques you already used, or at least how you described it to us).

1. You can verify against original package checksums using `rpm -V "$(rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/mount)"`, and more widely using `rpm -V --all`. In the output, you should generally ignore lines which include " c " as these represent config files which are allowed to be changed. You will see a lot of these when you use --all. Also ignore lines which say " g "; this means dynamically "generated" files including some logfiles. So you might want to use `rpm -V --all | grep -v " [cg] "`. It's probably worth trying the first approach which just checks the package for `mount` to start with, because that will be a nice quick check. http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-output.html
2. Given that you are on Fedora, a second horror to check for regarding "Permission denied", would be corruption of SELinux attributes. The program for this is `fixfiles`. For example, `fixfiles check`. This too is likely to provide a horrifying amount of output which is not relevant, because not even Fedora developers actually know how to use SELinux correctly. I feel useful suggestions for this command are even harder to find.  `fixfiles check /usr` should hopefully at least cover the specific error you have with /usr/bin/mount, while also looking for some wider damage, and avoiding the most noisy false positives.

---

> So far I have:
>
> - Checked disk health reported by SMART and performed both - short and long tests. Disk is perfectly healthy.

Right, it's always good to test SMART health.  And if you suspect disk corruption, running one of the tests (I assume long is best) is a good checklist item.

> - Checked filesystem integrity with fsck. All partitions are clean.

Good thought, but I have a nitpick. To specify that you have confirmed filesystem integrity, when faulty hardware appears to be a possibility, you must specify that you have run `fsck -f`.

(It is possible for the "dirty" state of a journalling filesystem such as ext4, to have been cleared by `fsck` or the kernel simply replaying the journal. In that case, running `fsck` without `-f` will simply report that the filesystem has been marked "clean", without checking any further.)

Also, you should specify that you're using ext4 for your root filesystem (assuming that's the case). If you use btrfs or maybe XFS, it's not necessarily the case that the traditional `fsck` command will achieve anything.

(In such cases filesystem-specific commands might be more helpful... or not.  Basically, the ext2 line of filesystems originally pre-dates journalling and so developed a `fsck` which was intended to be able to do a thorough integrity check.  Other filesystems have different histories.

btrfs and ZFS are "checksumming filesystems", written to detect errors on their own.  It would be reasonable to consider running a "scrub" at this point.  This would explicitly check data that has been written by the filesystem against the checksum that was generated at the time.  (This excludes certain types of files which opt out, for performance reasons).

For example, if data was corrupted in the process of being transmitted to the disk, a "scrub" would detect this, but a SMART test would not.)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I will try to follow your suggestions and let you know.

Comment: At the moment I have tried to mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue in  emergency mode and it returned no error, but /dev/mqueue folder is empty.

Comment: @p.h. ok. It's fine if that FS is empty, AFAIK. This shows your manual command was not affected by the error "spawning /usr/bin/mount: Permission denied". This surprises me. I suspect it will be hard to really debug that specific Permission denied error, so the broad-spectrum (but slow) checks might be more productive. SELinux is maybe slightly elevated as a candidate though.

Comment: I have followed your advices. Please take a look at points 4-7. Surprisingly fixfiles says file system is read only and that it would like to relabel /usr/sbin/mount.nilfs2.

Comment: SELinux is causing the problem as I have proved - see p. 9. How to examine why wisely?

Comment: @p.h. congrats. Although RPM does not mark those 6 files as "generated", files in `/var/lib/` tend to be so. (In previous versions, these specific files were in `/etc`, I guess that they have been moved correctly but the selinux people still do not understand RPM). But yes, corrupted selinux policy (or untested modifications) could in theory create this problem.

Comment: @p.h. Firstly, know that `SELINUX=disabled` stops maintaining correct SELinux labels. If you want to be able to use selinux again, you're supposed to use `SELINUX=permissive` instead. You would have to switch to that *first* (edit config and reboot), then run a full relabel. [Citation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html). An example of how to relabel is `fixfiles onboot && reboot`. A full relabel will take a long time, I am very sorry. But before trying to relabel I think we should look at the policy, because the policy could affect the relabel.

Comment: I think you can rebuild selinux policy with `semodule -B`. I think you can also check for local modifications to the source configs first, using `semanage module -C -l`. And to the file_contexts which fixfiles reads, with `semanage fcontext -C -l`.

Comment: I have changed SELinux mode to permissive and rebooted. During booting SELinux warning appeared saying targeted policy relabel is required. See photo added to the Google album. I'm waiting for it to finish.

Comment: @p.h. but I'm still not sure whether I expect this to help. You can check some of the `man` pages yourself to get a tiny bit more context.

Comment: @sorcejedi System booted after relabeling. I set enforcing mode just to test if it would boot, but the problem persists, so I have reverted to permissive mode. I'm going to follow your advices tomorrow.